# Calculate Panchanga elements Ending time

Tags: java, android

I am doing Panchanag Application in android by taking the date, time and location latitude and longitude. I am able to get all the elements (i.e., Thidi,Vaara,Nakshtra,Yoga and Karana). For each element i have to calculate the ending time.
I follow the below link for calculating ending times,

http://www.scribd.com/doc/18006659/Panchangam-Calculations

But i am not getting the Exact values, i compared the values with this site

http://www.drikpanchang.com/panchang/month-panchang.html?date=24/10/2013

I googled for other source but i did not find out any resource.

Is any body did this before,please help me.

Hello Seema can you please reply to my question - please help because I have also developed an ios app for astrology and now have the same issue you've had. Please refer to my question:

[How to calculate Daily motion for Sun and Moon astrology? Calculate Panchanga elements Ending time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48838886/how-to-calculate-daily-motion-for-sun-and-moon-astrology-calculate-panchanga-el)

Answer (score 0):

I have never dit that but if you can paste a sample of one of your formula, I'm sure that someone could help you. 
Just in case, when you do some divisions, do you cast all of your values in float (or double) ? Because one of the most common calculation problem is that :

```
int a = 10
int b = 3
float c = a / b
```

then c equals 3 and not 3.3333...
And I see that there is a loooooot of divisions in Panchangam Calculations.

If it's your problem, you should do that :

```
int a = 10
int b = 3
float c = a / (float)b
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i follwed this link for calculating panchanga elements https://github.com/santhoshn/panchanga/blob/master/plib.c

Comment: Another thing, if your result is not exact but verry verry close to the expected result, it may be that is due to the way that Java encode the float values like this (just an exemple, not true) : 
float f = 1.3; 
System.out.println(f); 
Should print something like 
1.2999999999999999998 
or
1.3000000000000000003 
or 
1.3 if you are lucky